# Linux command line get mongodb version

Tags: python, mongodb

I could get the version in command line, but how could I store it in variable:

```
In [28]: if subprocess.call('mongo --version', shell = True) == '':
   ....:     print 'Not installed'
   ....: else:
             print 'Already installed'
   ....:     print subprocess.call('mongo --version', shell = True)
   ....:     
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
0
```

is it possible to retrive only version value any store it in variable?

`v = subprocess.call('mongo --version', shell = True)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subprocess.check_call` returns the return code of the command.

Use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) which reutrn the output of the command as a byte string:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(['mongo', '--version'])
    version = output.split()[-1]  # get the last word: version
except (OSError, subprocess. CalledProcessError):
    version = None
```

You need to catch a exception `OSError` (subprocess will raise the exception if the command is not found), `CalledProcessError` (which will be raised if command was not run successfully).

Comment: Yep. And then extract value using regex (`re` module).

Comment: @ForceBru, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly but without using regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `mongo --version` you will get the mongodb **client** version, not the database engine version, but I not sure what really you want.

If you have the Python driver `PyMongo` installed, you can get the database engine version with:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(host=host, port=port)
print client.server_info()['version']
```